# Consulta SQL donde una condición seria exceptuar los registros que se duplican en un campo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Buenas gente estoy desarrollando una pagina donde se realizan varias consultas a bases de datos, estoy usando PHP y MySQL, la cuestión es que no puedo concluir una consulta que tenga por condición(entre otras) obtener los registros que tienen en el campo Estado = pendiente, exceptuando los que se repiten en el campo numero_expediente.
paso una imagen con la base de datos de prueba que estoy utilizando y el código de la consulta que en este caso me dice que una subconsulta se repite mas de una fila

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
el código de la consulta es la siguiente

```
$consulta = "SELECT seguimientos.*, usuarios.nombres, usuarios.apellidos FROM seguimientos, usuarios WHERE seguimientos.usuario_recepcion=(SELECT ID_usuarios FROM usuarios WHERE dni=".$_SESSION['sess_usuario'].") AND usuarios.ID_usuarios=seguimientos.usuario_envio AND seguimientos.estado='pendiente' AND NOT(SELECT A.ID_seguimiento FROM seguimientos A, seguimientos B WHERE A.numero_expediente = B.numero_expediente AND A.estado <> B.estado)";
```

-cabe aclarar que tengo que parametrizar dicha consulta luego, estoy abierto a consejos por cierto

esto es lo que me dice cuando ejecuto dicha consulta

"Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Muchas gracias!

Edito y agrego mas explicacion

primero aclarar que  los expedientes son trabajos(de diferente indolé), no hago ningun UPDATE porque tiene que quedar registrado todo el recorrido que hace el expediente desde que se crea por "Usuario A" (por ejemplo jefe de area) queda en "estado=iniciado",luego es enviado a la cuenta de "Usuario B" (por ejemplo un operativo del area de informatica) pasa a ser estado=pendiente, hasta que "Usuario B" habre dicho expediente para leer el trabajo requerido  que pasa a  "estado=leido", despues cuando "Usuario B" comienza a trabajarlo pasa a  estado=proceso y por ultimo cuando "Usuario B" o bien termina dicho trabajo o bien vuelve a enviar el expediente a un "Usuario C"(otro operativo) para complementar el trabajo y que este ultimo lo termine, ya dicho expediente pasa a un estado= Concluido... Espero que haya sido claro, en resumen esa tabla es todoo el seguimiento de dicho expediente y se requiere que quede todo registrado(crear registros nuevos por cada movimiento que se haga) nada de UPDATE.

*Nota: las fechas y horas no coinciden cronologicamente porque son inventadas solo para hacer pruebas.

Comment: No deberías actualizar el registro numero_expediente = 4? Por qué haces el insert? En este caso está pendiente y leído.

Comment: @Eric  edite y añadí al final una breve explicacion del porque no se hace una actualizacion al registro

Comment: @Ultimatux, en caso de haber más de un registro del mismo expediente, no debe mostrarse ninguno o debe mostrarse el último?

Comment: @GustavoCantero deberia ser de este modo  *en el caso de haber mas de un registro con el mismo expediente se debera mostrar el que diga leido, luego en caso de que haya 3 registros con el mismo expediente pero con estados diferentes ("pendiente", "leido","proceso") se debera mostrar el que diga proceso, pero ya con un ejemplo resolviendo la SQL que planteo en la pregunta, ya podré guiarme para hacer el resto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acá te dejo un ejemplo con algunos campos para que te guies, pero yo creo que el query debería ser así:

```
SELECT numero_expediente, estado
FROM seguimientos AS s1
WHERE estado = 'proceso'
  OR (estado = 'leido'
      AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM seguimientos AS s2 WHERE s2.numero_expediente = s1.numero_expediente AND s2.estado = 'proceso'))
  OR (estado = 'pendiente'
      AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM seguimientos AS s2 WHERE s2.numero_expediente = s1.numero_expediente AND s2.estado != 'pendiente'))
```

Creo que con eso se entiende la idea y puedes continuar con el join a usuario y el resto.

Aprovecho a hacerte una recomendación: siempre es mejor guardar todo lo que se pueda nomenclado en lugar de poner textos, en este caso me refiero al estado, porque para el motor le es mucho más rápido comparar `estado = 1` que `estado = 'proceso'`.

Comment: Gustavo probé solo el  código que pasaste, independiente del mio para ver el resultado que devolvía pero me arrojo una leyenda al ejecutarlo: _You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1_ , de todos modos igual me desbloqueo las ideas con dicho código

Comment: Tenés razón, me faltaron dos paréntesis.  Ya lo corregí y ahora funciona sin errores.

Comment: Gustavo tu codigo si funciona si bien no es exacto lo que busco pero al menos me encamino, ahora bien para ser mas exacto sigo probando y no logro dar con la consulta deseada. Mira para ser puntual necesitaria por ejemplo una consulta que me devuelva el ID_seguimiento = 4 ,obviamente que sin usar constantes porque mediante dicha consulta lo adaptaria al resto, tengo este codigo      `"SELECT s1.ID_seguimiento FROM seguimientos AS s1, seguimientos AS s2 WHERE s1.estado ='pendiente' AND s1.numero_expediente = s2.numero_expediente";`    el mismo me devuelve 4; 4; 5; 6;

Comment: Disculpá @Ultimatux, pero no entiendo con qué condiciones buscas el ID_seguimiento.  Si ese campo es único, no entiendo el sentido de traerlo en s1 y s2.  ¿Podrías ser más específico, por favor?

Comment: En tu consulta te devuelve dos veces el 4 porque encuentra el id de seguimiento 4 y le hace un join con el mismo 4 y el 7, ya que ambos tienen el mismo número de expediente.

Comment: ahora no entiendo 2 cosas:        1)- Nose porque me devuelve dos veces el mismo    `ID_seguimiento = 4;`   2)-En teoria si uso el operador _AND_ tendria que ser verdaderos ambas condiciones pero solo el ID_seguimiento=4 tiene en estado='pendiente' y tambien su numero_expediente repetido

Comment: puntualmente hice referencia al ID =4 porque en cierta lista que debo imprimir en pantalla no deberia aparecer con los demas pendientes porque ya tiene otro registro de su expediente con estado= leido   .Me disculpo si lo hago muy extenso, es que nunca trabaje con comparaciones de una misma tabla y se me esta complicando no terminar de entender algunas cuestiones